# Viewing URLs on Mobile Devices

Tags: email, mobile, url

What are you doing to help your users view URLs in emails on mobile devices? Our training program is helping people to understand how to view URLs before clicking the actual link. On mobile devices this is difficult and every attempt is a risk due to having to hold press to highlight or copy the information.

What suggestions do you all have other than copying the URL into another app to view the text, disabling your cellular and wifi before attemping to hold-press to view the URL, or waiting until you reach a desktop device for suspiscious emails?

Comment: whats the risk?

Comment: @VipulNair The risk is what ever is on the other side of the link.

Comment: It’s worth a mention for iOS developers the old UIWebView is less secure than the current WebKit implementations. I don’t do anything to help the user see a URL before tapping but I do use the modern browser implementations.

Comment: Why is a hold-press a problem?

Comment: Do you mean this situation? -> 1. On a mobile device, the email app may receive some spam emails including malicious URLs. If the users click the URL without verify the link is secure, they would be directed to some malicious website. 2. Thus, you want to have an approach to treat the URL as text only, check the security of URL, before clicking them as a real link.

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 ways to achieve your goal.

- Safer and easier way:

  Use an anti-malware solution that will help you to block the phishing links. Keep the signatures of this anti-malware solution up to date.
- Risky and harder method:

  Jailbreak your mobile phone, then write a script that collects IP/domain feed from Open Threat intel sources like [OTX alienvault](https://www.alienvault.com/open-threat-exchange), [VirusTotal](https://developers.virustotal.com/reference), etc. Then block the connections to this IPs/Domains. You may want to use it in cron to make it dynamic list.

Comment: This does not answer the question about how to help users view/check the URL